# Laravel login not working in production but works locally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a laravel project which works fine locally. the entire app is in a laravel container.

I initiate the login using axios as shown below

```
axios.post(this.route('api.customers.login'), {
                    email: this.customer.email,
                    password: this.customer.pwd
                }).then(async response => {
                    console.log('debug', response)
                    location.reload(); //once reloaded I can see that the user has been logged in - locally but not on my server


                }).catch(function (error) {
                    self.loading = false
                    self.error = true
                });
```

Server-side I have

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $customer = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')), true)) {
            return response()->json([
                'user' => $user,
            ]);
        }
        ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Unauthorized",
        ], 401);

    }
```

The project is hosted on AWS using ECS and a Load balancer.
I also have HTTPS listener setup on the LB which redirects HTTP to HTTPS.
I also have my session stored in the DB - RDS instance so its decoupled and so is my cache - redis.

I have a feeling its to do with my setup since this works perfectly fine on my mac (docker-compose).

It appears the right cookies are not being set.

Any insights?

Comment: What driver you are using in customer guard?

Comment: I am using the session driver

Comment: It looks like you need to get some debugging information out of the system. 

check the network tab of your browser's web development tools for information about the axios request. 

check the laravel log file for any backend errors

temporarily add a console.log(); to the catch portion of that axios command, and watch your browser console for information while submitting.

Comment: Yes, this is the thing, the axios returns a 200 success with my desired json payload. The issue is when I go to other pages, the user isn't authenticated. It's alsmot like it doesn't know who it is after the axios call. Do you know what laravel does once its logged in, what cookies should I look out for?

Comment: You cannot use session driver for auth thought axios. For this you need token - see laravel/sanctum package

Comment: But how ocme it works locally on my mac?